# How to use Dictionary in Windows phone let the key be reference to method

Tags: windows-phone-7, voice-recognition

I am developing an application for Windows phone that will take my voice commands and make a button. I am trying to let the voice recognition to take his value grammar from the dictionary, how can that be done?

Here are where the voice recognition will take the value from the List:

```
_recognizer.Grammars.AddGrammarFromList("voiceCommand", _webBrowserCommand.Keys);
```

and here is the voice command class:

```
class  voiceCommand
{
    WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();

    public voiceCommand( )
    {

    }
    public void backWord() {
        if (web.CanGoBack) 
        web.GoBack();
    }
    private void forkWord()
    {
        if(web.CanGoForward)
        web.GoForward();
    }
    private void refreash() {

        var currentSource = web.Source;
        web.Source = null;
        web.Source = currentSource;
    }


    }}
```

I do something like that but it's give  me syntax error :

```
if (_webBrowserCommand == null)
        {
            _webBrowserCommand = new Dictionary<string, voiceCommand>();
            _webBrowserCommand.Add("Backword", new voiceCommand());}
```

Comment: It's really quite difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Please don't make it hard for us to help you. You should do more work to make this question easy to answer.

Comment: sorry, I wrote my problem in clearly but i did not see that some words are missing , and i don't know how to edit it ... my problem that i want the program to accept the voice command from the user and make an action that buttons made like if i they want to open the favorite on the web browser the don't need to press a button just say it to the phone and it will recognize their commands and make an action .I found that the voice recognition accept his grammar from Dictionary as a list , I have a sample that the voice recognize the color,in my app i want him to recognize the actions as methods

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes better sense to me now. So the problem I have is that I don't know the recognizer and I don't know the method `AddGrammarFromList`. You would have to define those for me to be able to help.